# Install cURL compiled with OpenSSL and zlib in Dockerfile

Tags: php, apache, curl, docker, debian

I need to install cURL compiled with OpenSSL and zlib via Dockerfile for Debian image with apache and php 5.6. I tried many approaches but due to the fact that I don't have string understanding in Linux a failed. I use docker-compose to up my container. docker-compose.yaml looks like:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: php -S 0.0.0.0:80 -t /var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - $PWD/www/project:/var/www/html
    container_name: "project-web-server"
  db:  
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "192.168.99.100:3306:3306"
    container_name: "project-db"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
      MYSQL_USER: dbuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: dbpass
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dbpass
```

As a build script I use Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \ 
    apt-utils \
    curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl php5-mcrypt
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) curl
```

'docker-php-ext-install' is a helper script from the base image https://hub.docker.com/_/php/

The problem is that after `$ docker build --rm .` which is successful a don't get an image with cURL+SSL+zlib. After `$ docker-compose up` I have a working container with Apache+MySQL and can run my project but libraries I need are not there.

Could you explain how to add these extensions to my apache in container properly? I even tried to create my own Dockerfile and build apache+php+needed libs there, but had no result.

Answer (score 0):

Your Dockerfile is not complete.   You have not done a COPY (or similar) to transfer your source code to execute from the host into the container.   The point of a Dockerfile is to setup an environment together with your source code which finishes by launching a process (typically a server).

```
COPY code-from-some-location  into-location-in-container

CMD path-to-your-server
```

... as per the URL you reference a more complete Dockerfile would appear like this

```
FROM php:5.6-cli
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
CMD [ "php", "./your-script.php" ]
```

notice the COPY which recursively copies all files/dirs (typically the location of your source code, etc like data and/or config files) in your $PWD where you execute the command onto the specified location internal to the container   In unix a period as in . indicates the current directory so above command

```
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
```

will copy all files and directories in current directory from the host computer (the one you are using when typing in the docker build command) into the container directory called /usr/src/myapp

the WORKDIR acts to change directories into your container's dir supplied

finally the CMD launches the server which hums along once your launch the container

Comment: Thank you. I read the reference for COPY in Dockerfile and still don't understand what I should copy. I mean that I map volumes in docker-compose.yaml. When the containers run the server from "project-web-server" container works with my local project files. But cURL with SSL and zlib are not apache extensions regarding phpinfo and code errors from my scripts.

Comment: a Dockerfile is just a series of commands which get executed to create your docker image ... You need to use a COPY command to transfer your local project files into the container that is what the COPY . /some/path/inside/container   is doing ....  I suggest you first get working a simpler docker container ... remember only ONE process per container